# How to replace an inputted string with values from two different arrays javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

I am trying to update a string to its corresponding values with two arrays

**Here is the set up**

An array of english characters with corresponding leet characters

```
let letters = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' ];
let leetChars = ['@', '8', '(', '|)', '3', 'ph', 'g', '#','l', '_|', '|<', '1', "|'|'|", '/\/', '0', '|D', '(,)', '|2', '5', '+', '|_|', '|/', "|/|/'",'><', 'j', '2'];
```

Given a string I want to be able to return a new string containing the corresponding leet characters of the given original string.

for example `'Multiverse'` should be `"|'|'||_|1+l|/3|253"`

**My Approach**

I have created a function `leetTranslator` that accepts a a string(of normal characters) as a parameter.I've declared a variable `translation` which will hold the new string and i created a loop however i'm struggling to replace the original strings characters with the corresponding leet value.

**This is what i have**

```
function leetTranslator (str){
    let translation="";
  
        for (i=0;i<str.length;i++){
            translation=str.replace(/str/gi , letters );
            
        }
        
    return translation ;
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use an object instead of the two arrays; then the translation is a simple matter of looking up the value of the letter to be translated:

```js
var leetChars = {
  a: "@", b: "8", c: "(", d: "|)", e: "3",
  f: "ph", g: "g", h: "#", i: "l", j: "_|",
  k: "|<", l: "1", m: "|'|'|", n: "//", o: "0",
  p: "|D", q: "(,)", r: "|2", s: "5", t: "+",
  u: "|_|", v: "|/", w: "|/|/'", x: "><", y: "j",
  z: "2"
}

function leetTranslator(str) {
    let translation = "";
    for (i = 0; i < str.length ; i++){
       translation += leetChars[str[i]] || str[i];
    }
    return translation;
}

console.log(leetTranslator('hello world!'))
```

Note you can use built-in functions to simplify your code:

```js
var leetChars = {
  a: "@", b: "8", c: "(", d: "|)", e: "3",
  f: "ph", g: "g", h: "#", i: "l", j: "_|",
  k: "|<", l: "1", m: "|'|'|", n: "//", o: "0",
  p: "|D", q: "(,)", r: "|2", s: "5", t: "+",
  u: "|_|", v: "|/", w: "|/|/'", x: "><", y: "j",
  z: "2"
}

const leetTranslator = str =>
  str.split('')
    .map(c => leetChars[c] || c)
    .join('')

console.log(leetTranslator('hello world!'))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Map](https://javascript.info/map-set) i think it works well

```
let map = new Map([
['a', '@'],
['b', '8'],
['c', '('],
//etc.
]);


function leetTranslator (str){
let translation="";

    for (i=0;i<str.length;i++){
        translation=map.get(i);
    }
    
return translation ;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a regex, you can just check each letter in turn.

```js
let letters = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' ];
let leetChars = ['@', '8', '(', '|)', '3', 'ph', 'g', '#','l', '_|', '|<', '1', "|'|'|", '/\/', '0', '|D', '(,)', '|2', '5', '+', '|_|', '|/', "|/|/'",'><', 'j', '2'];

function leetTranslator (str){
  return str.split("")
    .map(s => letters.includes(s) ? leetChars[letters.indexOf(s)] : s)
    .join("");
}

console.log(leetTranslator("multiverse"));
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you require you can use `map()` to create an array of the leet characters, by matching the index of the current character in the string. Then you can just `join('')` it together to return the new string:

```js
let letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
let leetChars = ['@', '8', '(', '|)', '3', 'ph', 'g', '#', 'l', '_|', '|<', '1', "|'|'|", '/\/', '0', '|D', '(,)', '|2', '5', '+', '|_|', '|/', "|/|/'", '><', 'j', '2'];

let leetTranslator = str => [...str.toLowerCase()].map(c => leetChars[letters.indexOf(c)]).join('');

let multiverseOutput = leetTranslator('Multiverse');
console.log(multiverseOutput );
```

Note the use of `toLowerCase()` here, as your original `letters` array has no uppercase characters.

Comment: So what if you want to make it case insensitive?

Comment: Remove `toLowerCase()` and add all the uppercase letters to the `letters` array, and their equivalents to the `leetChars` array

Comment: isn't there a way to be able to make it accept both upper and lower case at the same time . for example by using the case insensitive flag(//i)

Comment: Sure, but that's effectively what `toLowerCase()` is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Since the array is same length, you can map the two arrays.

```js
let letters = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' ];

let leetChars = ['@', '8', '(', '|)', '3', 'ph', 'g', '#','l', '_|', '|<', '1', "|'|'|", '/\/', '0', '|D', '(,)', '|2', '5', '+', '|_|', '|/', "|/|/'",'><', 'j', '2'];

let mappingObject = {};

letters.forEach((letter, index) => {
  mappingObject[letter] = leetChars[index];
});


function leetTranslator(str) {
  let result = '';
  for (i=0;i<str.length;i++){
    result = result + mappingObject[str[i].toLowerCase()];
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(leetTranslator('Multiverse'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by using [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method.

Live Demo (All the descriptive comments has been added in the below code snippet itself) **:**

```js
let letters = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' ];
let leetChars = ['@', '8', '(', '|)', '3', 'ph', 'g', '#','l', '_|', '|<', '1', "|'|'|", '/\/', '0', '|D', '(,)', '|2', '5', '+', '|_|', '|/', "|/|/'",'><', 'j', '2'];

// This function is used to convert the input string into a leetChars string.
function leetCharsStr(str) {
  // Declare a variable with an empty string
  let result = '';
  // Split the input string and iterate over each character
  str.split('').forEach(c => {
    // Find the index of the passed character 'c' from the letters array.
    const index = letters.indexOf(c.toLowerCase());
    // Concat the mapped leetchar into a result string. 
    result += leetChars[index];
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(leetCharsStr('Multiverse'));
```

Comment: What if you want to accept both upper and lower case string

Comment: @Mist In that case you can convert both into either lowercase or uppercase.